# How to drop a table in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

In MySQL, for the useless data, we can use the DROP TABLE command to delete it from the database. However, for the TDengine database, which SQL command can allow me to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the same routine to drop database/table as this is pretty much the same follows SQL standard:
drop database db_name
drop table tb_name